# Multiple matches within lookback/lookahead in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match multiple strings surrounded by specific words in Javascript:
this is my example:

```
{{#tooltip}}
  {{classes}}
  {{>117-tooltip
      classes=(concat classes " myclasses")
      noLinks=true
  }}
  {{classes}}
{{/tooltip}}
```

{{/unless}}
{{/tooltip}}

Now I want to match all occurrences of `{{classses}}` or  `classes` that are written after {{#tooltip}} and before {{/tooltip}}

This is my current approach:

```
(?<={{#tooltip}})([.\s\S]*?[{{ ](classes)[}} ][.\s\S]*)*(?={{\/tooltip}})
```

Currently it only matches the first `classes` and not all of them, what am I missing?

Here's the link to the regex101:
https://regex101.com/r/HwFDhI/5

Comment: Does `(?:\G(?!\A)|{{#tooltip}})(?:(?!{{\/?#tooltip}})[\s\S])*?\K({{)?classes(?(1)}})`  work for you? See https://regex101.com/r/DHnrp1/1

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew, this works perfectly fine for PHP! Does it also work for JS? I get an error because of the ? not being quantifiable

Comment: Do you need it for  JS only?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, only for JS

Comment: You need a parser here. The structures are nested.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
/(?<={{#tooltip}}(?:(?!{{[/#]tooltip}}).)*?)(classes|{{classes}})(?=(?:(?!{{[/#]tooltip}}).)*{{\/tooltip}})/gsi
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/BoKq1Q/1/).

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {{#tooltip}}             '{{#tooltip}}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        {{                       '{{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [/#]                     any character of: '/', '#'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        tooltip}}                'tooltip}}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    classes                  'classes'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {{classes}}              '{{classes}}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        {{                       '{{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [/#]                     any character of: '/', '#'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        tooltip}}                'tooltip}}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {{                       '{{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    tooltip}}                'tooltip}}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

**JavaScript code**:

```js
const string = "{{#tooltip}}\n  {{classes}}\n  {{>117-tooltip\n      classes=(concat classes \" myclasses\")\n      noLinks=true\n  }}\n  {{classes}}\n{{/tooltip}}";
const regex = /(?<={{#tooltip}}(?:(?!{{[/#]tooltip}}).)*?)(classes|{{classes}})(?=(?:(?!{{[/#]tooltip}}).)*{{\/tooltip}})/gsi;
console.log(string.match(regex));
```